# ASP.NET TCP прослушивание

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Можно ли слушать TCP порт в ASP.NET web rest API проекте?

Comment: а кто этот порт слушать будет если у вас web rest api? опишите подробнее, что именно вы хотите получить.

Comment: мне нужно постоянное соединение, но я не знаю в каком протоколе работать..

Comment: Asp вообще и web api в частности, это про http, а для него постоянных соединений не существует. Если нужно постоянное соединение, используйте обычный tcp-сервер или wcf, он тоже так умеет, даже клиента за колбек дернуть может